Curl sending requests in parallel extremely slow
I tried to use curl command to send HTTP requests in parallel like echo {1..10} | xargs -n1 -P10 curl -s -o /dev/null https://www.google.com. The command run on my Mac is super fast (less than 1s), but when I ran it on an Ubuntu 22.04 instance on AWS EC2, it is extremely slow (several minutes).
I tested the bandwidth of two mahines using speedtest-cli. The download speed on my Mac is only 300 Mibt/s while on EC2 instance it is more than 900 Mbit/s. The curl version on my Mac is 8.1.2 and on EC2 instance it is 7.68.0. It seems the problem is not on network or curl but the handling of xargs.

Instead of using -s silent flag of curl, you can use -v or --verbose flag to debug the curl action, if you find the speed abnormal.
